# SharePoint 2013 ribbon is missing (hidden)

Tags: 2013, ribbon, tools

I don't know what happened but suddenly my SharePoint 2013 ribbon disappeared. When I click Edit Page, it doesn't show me the ribbon.

Comment: What did you do before that? I mean did you change anything in master page?

Comment: Ok forget about it, my sharepoint is crazy, i refresh it many times and magically the ribbon appears.

Comment: So consider deleting your questing

Comment: Known issue (although I can't find a reference in 10 seconds). I recall it has something to do with multiple webparts on a page and the ribbon is restored when you click an item in the list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is only in list views where that occurs Danny. We have several places where people have done that and it annoys the hell out of me..

Answer (score 3):

To get the ribbon back, click the Settings wheel then click **Show Ribbon**.

Comment: why would they add this feature when they suck at adding features... i was happily editing my page until i realized there was no save button, then i restored it to find out the page wasn't even editable because someone else had it checked out the whole time... when are they going to add the feature that makes SharePoint blow me D:

Answer (score 0):

I had created a Register site based on the Site Contents App "Lists".  I wanted a subheading and created one using the web part.  The ribbon bar disappeared from my views.   To ensure this doesn't happen, before adding a new web part you need to create another view, so that you have "All Items" and something else.  In the "All Items" view, create your new web part.  The ribbon bar will disappear, but your second view will have it available for use.  Not sure of another way of doing this.  JR